# Integral of a rectangle expressed in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus

As part of a derivation, I need to find the value of the integral

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} r(\theta) \, d\theta$$

where $r(\theta)$ describes a rectangular region of dimensions $2a \times 2b$, i.e. $[-a,a]\times [-b,b]\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$.

I understand to split the region up into four triangular regions bounded by $\pm \arctan(b/a)$ and $\pm \arctan(b/a)$, where $r(\theta)$ takes either the value $a|\sec(\theta)|$ or $b|\csc(\theta)|$, but I am stuck actually evaluating the integral and substituting the bounds.

Edit: dimensions $2a$ by $2b$ for simplicity.

Comment: $\int_0^{2\pi} r(\theta) d \theta = 4a\cdot \int_0^{\theta_0} \sec \theta d \theta + 4b\cdot \int_{\theta_0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \csc \theta d \theta$ where $\theta_0 = \arctan \frac{b}{a}$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

[image]

If the rectangle is taken $(2a \times  2b)$ as shown, the first two definite integrals are:

$$ \int _{-\tan^{-1}(b/a)}^{\tan^{-1}(b/a)} a \sec \theta d \theta   + \int _{\tan^{-1}(b/a)}^{\pi-\tan^{-1}(b/a)} b \csc \theta d \theta \; + ...+... $$

Similarly you can express the next two symmetric  integrals to integrate and sum up.